# iOS - In App Purchases - Restore button?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have seen some things about Apple rejecting your app if you don't offer a "restore purchases" option. I have never seen this in an app, but granted I don't do much in-app purchasing myself. My question is, how are you guys implementing this? Not the code to do it, but where do you put the button? Do you just put a "Restore In-App Purchases" button in some random place in your app? Or do you wait for them to make a purchase and then somehow check if they've made purchases and offer them the option to restore everything?

Any examples of this in other apps is appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most apps I have seen with this put it in the accounts section of app settings. Since it is usually related to purchases made on your account within the app, I feel this would be the best place and most likely place users of your app would check, if such a feature was ever needed.

Comment: Do you mean in the main iOS Settings App?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a way to add buttons in the Settings app. Only switches and disclosures.

Comment: And you can't run code from the Settings App either, so how would you execute the restore from here?

Comment: I've never heard of doing this before could you explain more? Give some examples of apps that do it? EDIT: just saw @alazaro 's answer... weird. Any idea how they did that?

Comment: @soleil You don't show it in the iOS settings menu, but in a settings menu in your app.

Comment: @Bot, oh ok, makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

I implement it like that.
In the AppDelegate call isIAPRestoreNeeded when app starts AND get active:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SettingsKeyIAPRestoreNeeded"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SettingsKeyIAPRestoreNeeded"];

    // IAP restore
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

The corresponding settings entry must be of course in the Settings bundle of the app. In my opinion the best solution, because it doesn't destroy the UI and UX of the app.

Comment: From my experience if you do this automatically Apple do not like it. It's recommended to include a button that the user can press in order to do it. This is simply due to the fact it prompts the user to log into their iTunes account. If a random prompt comes up asking for your password the user is less likely to enter their details.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Photoshop Express](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235?mt=8) has a section in settings (in the app) where you can buy items or restore purchases. You can download it and check it out for free.

Answer (score 0):

You should show it at all times, as the main point of it is if you delete and reinstall your app, you lose your in app purchases. So you press the button to get them back.
I'd put it on the same view as the In App Purchases themselves. Just a tiny button or line of text should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about show it in the Settings app? Maybe you'll want it on the page where you sell your content in a Navigation Bar as a button? Or if you have categorized settings in-app, make a new category pertaining to your IAP and add a restore button there?

Comment: I don't think you can put it in the Settings app, because it needs to be a button that executes code. AFAIK, you can only put switches, etc. in the Settings app.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example at :

http://itunes.com/apps/snowboardlingo

(A free App snowboard Quiz/reference with In App Purchase)

The restore button is on the App 'Information page' (the i symbol). Apple Documents say that users will 'hunt around' for this button..